# There is getting a error when i am filtering data with array

Tags: reactjs

```
const [searchData, setSearchData] =useState([]);
const searchRecord = async (value) => {
    const searchName = activeLabDetailsData.filter(name => value.user.name === name);
    setSearchData(true);
}
<input type="text" onChange={()=> searchRecord(setSearchData)} placeholder="Enter lab" name="search2" />
```

Comment: What error?????

Comment: @jitendra, please provide more information on the error you are receiving.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

You don't do anything with the filter result. You mutate the `searchData` state invariant from an array to a boolean. `searchRecord` is passed your state updater function (*it doesn't have a `user` property*). This last one is likely the cause of any errors you may be seeing in the `.filter` callback.

## Solution

1. Pass the `onChange` event's target value to the `searchRecord` handler.
2. Filter by the passed `value` in the `searchRecord` callback.
3. Save the filtered array result `searchName` into the state.
4. Since nothing is awaited in `searchRecord` it doesn't need to be declared `async`.
5. When filtering the data it's common to use case-insensitive string comparisons.

code

```
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([]);

const searchRecord = (value) => {
  const searchName = activeLabDetailsData.filter(
    name => name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase)
  );
  setSearchData(searchName);
}

...

<input
  type="text"
  onChange={(event)=> searchRecord(event.target.value)}
  placeholder="Enter lab"
  name="search2"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew, it is very usable concept for me.